# use .htaccess for friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I've read many of the similar questions but have not been able to alter the url to an SEO friendly name.  It's bizarre because I believe my requirement should be simple. So I'm going to be specific in hopes of finding out what I'm missing.  I'm doing my testing on a local machine before I put it up on the server.

Here's what I got:

```
http://localhost/ggs2/forms/mymain.php
```

Here's what I want

```
http://localhost/ggs2/goals
```

In the ggs2 subdirectory I have an .htaccess file that reads:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/goals$ /forms/mymain.php
```

When I click on the link to the target the URL has not been modified.

So:

- Is there a problem with the .htaccess file?
- Is there some server setting I need to set?
- Something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^goals/?$ /forms/mymain.php [NC,L]
```

The first slash is removed, which means you were looking for the root folder, not the current folder.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, the URL didn't change.  It's still shows the original link '/forms/mymain.php'.

Comment: do you have more than 1 .htaccess? or other rules in the .htaccess?

Comment: No I don't.  Is there some Server setting that I need to set to enable the RewriteEngine?

Comment: I think you got whats wrong, check if mod_rewrite is enable. Do you have a simple rewriterule that works?